# Using rpad function to remote mySQL does not work

Tags: clickhouse

I tried to execute rpad function to remote mySQL server version 5.7 in a query and it gives an error DB::Exception: Unknown function rpad. Maybe you meant: ['rand']. But executing the same query on mySQL works fine. Appreciate if there is any workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the expected behavior. CH does not have such function. It can be emulated using length/repeat. CH does not push down this to Mysql because of two reasons 1. CH does not know Mysql SQL syntax, 2 Mysql engine exists to move ALL calculations into CH except basic filtering.

If you still need rpad in mysql you can create a view in mysql and query this view.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating a view in mySQL and used a query on view to move the data.